# Image doesn't load to window

Tags: c++, sdl

**Solution:** 
Works when writing the whole image adress instead of only the name

I know I asked a similar question recently but I haven't got a solution yet. I'm trying to load a simple bmp picture to a window in c++ and SDL. This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //init
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //screen window
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 32,  SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( WINDOW_TITLE, 0 );

    //image
    SDL_Surface *background = IMG_Load("images.png");

    SDL_Event event;
    bool gameRunning = true;

    //loop
    while (gameRunning)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                gameRunning = false;
            }

        }
        SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, screen, NULL);


        //update screen
        SDL_Flip(screen);

    }
    //quit 
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or can be a problem with my computer? I know I have placed the image in the project folder and spelt it the right way.

Comment: I can display an image using your code. Are you sure that you providing the correct file path to the image? Check that `background` is not null.

Comment: How do I check for null?

Comment: `std::cout << (background == NULL) << std::endl;` This will print `0` if it is not null.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, and if it is null then the image path is incorrect right?

Comment: Yes, if it is null (i.e. not `0`) the path is incorrect. Try placing the image in the same directory as your source file.

Comment: I think SDL only supports bmps by default, convert .png to .bmp and try again.

Comment: @user1095108 He is using SDL_image which supports .png's and many other formats. He probably forgot to link the appropriate libraries or didn't enter a proper file location.

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen Have you tried to copy the image to the same folder where the application is built (i.e. where the executable binary file is)?

Comment: @user2448027 I have placed the image in the same folder as the main.cpp, which are my source file. But it keeps returning NULL

Comment: @Garee it returns null even though I have placed the image in the same folder as my main.cpp file (source file)

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen I mean that you could try to place it in the same folder where your program is, e.g. `ProjectFolder/Output`, `ProjectFolder/bin`, `ProjectFolder/Debug` or `ProjectFolder/Release`.

Comment: I solved the problem, before I was just writing images.png. But it works when I'm writing the whole adress of the image